# How to add a ramp in a flash game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am a huge novice and this isn't really a programming question, but here I go, say I want to make a game that involves rolling up a ramp [like this one:](http://diyskate.com/img/ramps/mini_03/18.gif)

to move upwards, similar to how it would work in an old Sonic the Hedgehog game or something, how would I go about doing that, where could I find a good recourse to learn this?

Comment: start with this:  http://www.amazon.com/Absolute-Beginners-Guide-2nd-Edition/dp/0672305100/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1352078203&sr=8-1&keywords=absolute+beginner%27s+guide+to+c

Comment: "this isn't really a programming question" - ahem!

Answer (score 1):

When you move up a ramp, you gain potential energy.  Effectively, your kinetic energy turns into potential energy.

```
K = 0.5 * m * v^2

P = 0.5 * m * g * h
```

Where:

- `K` is kinetic energy
- `P` is potential energy
- `m` is mass
- `v` is velocity
- `g` is gravity
- `h` is height

Because you are animating, the easiest thing is to use the instantaneous velocity at the current frame to estimate the position in the next frame.  And you avoid having to integrate equations.

All you need is the change in height.  Let's say you move from `h0` to `h1`...  This gives you the new kinetic energy `K1`, meaning your speed decreases:

```
K1 = 0.5 * m * v^2 - (h1-h0) * m * g
```

And to get the new velocity `v1`:

```
0.5 * m * v1^2 = K1

               = 0.5 * m * v^2 - (h1-h0) * m * g

0.5 * m * (v1^2 - v^2) = -(h1-h0) * m * g

v1 = sqrt( v^2 - (h1 - h0) * g )
```

You then figure out your new position, clamp it to the ramp and find the ramp normal at that position.  You use that to adjust your direction unit-vector and multiply that vector by the new velocity to get your new `x`, `y` and `z` velocity components.